# Trackpad clicks register as command-click after sign in

Tags: high-sierra, trackpad, click

The trackpad on my MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) running 10.13.3 will occasionally register command clicks instead of normal "left" clicks after returning from sleep.

Neither command key is show as being down (verified with keyboard viewer). I used the event viewer on Karabiner-Elements to see what was happening.

The problem sometimes resolves seemingly of its own accord, other times I must restart.

I've shut down all running apps and menubar utilities, but nothing seems to effect the issue.

I'm perplexed as to what the deal is. I can't replicate the problem.

Comment: Create a temporary user account in **System Preferences ... > Users & Groups**. Does the problem recur?

Comment: The problem with the issue is that I have no way of reliably recreating it, so I need to wait for it to happen during the course of normal use, and it's not practical for me to work from a hobbled temporary environment.